# Macbook Air (2020) sudden increase in storage

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, storage, data

Today I closed my Macbook then opened it again 4 hours later and the available storage went from 15.1 gb to 21.6gb. (I know that's very low for MacOS). I checked with Disk Inventory X and Grand Perspective and it got the same result.

Is this some sort of glitch or malware?

Is this because my Mac cleared up some old cache or time machine backup?

Or is it some sort of corrupted data or data loss?

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about an increase as much as a decrease. (As long as you have a backup.) It could be that old APFS snapshots have been released; or the Trash emptying automatically after 30 days; or some other temp files clearing.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely some cache or similar being released (APFS snapshot, auto-trash-emptying,...).

E.g. iCloud (assuming you use iCloud services) uses caching to have files readily available, instead of having to download them every single time. Of course, it does not download your whole iCloud, but tries to figure out which files you need the most often.

Another possible scenario is auto-updates, where the update would be automatically downloaded and installed.

> Is this some sort of glitch or malware?

These questions are really hard to give a definitive answer because theoretically this could be malware, but what are the chances? Close to 0.

> Or is it some sort of corrupted data or data loss?

Unlikely. MBA from 2020 has an SSD that quite safely can last a decade.